# iOS: Adding UISearchbar with filter Options in a tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar

I am relatively new to iOS (coming from android background), and I would like to know how to implement and have a searchbar like in these two pictures https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQKE5.jpg and here(linkedin) https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnIG2.png . Would like to know **how to make make the filters/options appear dynamicly when users clicks on search field** and affect the results shown in the uitable. Example on linkedin 4 filters appear when user clicks on search. I have search on the net but I didn't manage to find persistent results. Again, **what I want to know is how to show those options/filters when user click on searchbar**

Any help is apreaciated, code or sample/ existing projects  would be very useful.

Thank you all in advanced

Answer (score 3):

UIKit comes with a dedicated built-in solution for searching in conjunction with a `UITableViewController`, called `UISearchDisplayController`. It provides everything (albeit without much customization), including the search bar view, an optional scope bar for filtering, and transitions.

Reference:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchDisplayController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

**Edit:**

Here is a tutorial: http://www.appcoda.com/search-bar-tutorial-ios7/

And here is another one that includes a scope bar: http://www.raywenderlich.com/16873/how-to-add-search-into-a-table-view

**Edit: All of this is obsolete now**

iOS8 introduces a new class `UISearchController` to make this much cleaner.
See http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2015/02/16/updating-to-the-ios-8-search-controller.html

Comment: I didn't find a tutorial for optional bar for filtering, any links please?

Comment: And one with a "scope bar"!